# UITabBar not visible in models higher than iPhone 4S

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have a project I am upgrading from Xcode 4.6.3 to Xcode 6.1.1 and adding auto layout.  The MainWindow.xib has a UITabBarController containing a UINavigationController containing a UIView which contains View with a UITableView.

[image: MainWindow Tab Bar Controller]

Selecting a cell in the table loads a details .xib like this:

```
TaskDetailsViewController *controller = [[TaskDetailsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TaskDetailsViewController" bundle:nil];
            controller.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
            self.taskDetailsViewController = controller;
            [controller release];
```

Before checking Use Auto Layout on the details xib, the tab bar on the bottom was visible.  After Use Auto Layout and adding constraints in IB, the tab bar on the bottom is not visible in a simulator higher than iPhone 4S. There is white space, and more white space than the height of the tab bar.  I tried moving frames and constraints of the contained views up from the bottom with no success.  In simulator iPhone 4S the details tab bar is visible.  Same result when running in a device.  All the details views are Alignment Rectangle.  The Tab Bar dimensions are disabled with X = 0, Y = 551, width = 600, and height = 49.

In the debugger looking at recursiveDescription from the MainWindow, the bottom UILayoutGuide has frame = (0 431; 0 0) and the UITabBar has frame = (0 431; 320 49), which is as intended.  After selecting a table cell and loading the details .xib, the details bottom UILayoutGuide has frame = (0 607; 0 0) and the UITabBar has frame = (0 607; 320 49).  607 doesn’t seem correct.  How can I get the details .xib UITabBar to be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

The TaskDetailsViewController nib has a view with nothing.  There is a sibling UITabBarController with the details tabs.  My solution was to make a storyboard with the UITabBarController, eliminating TaskDetailsViewController and view.  The tab bar can be laid out as expected.